# How can I simplify series of Label controls on click?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have 14 Labels, which are named Label_1,Label_2.... Label_14 .. etc,
and I want to detect which one is be click.

This code can run:

```
Private Sub Label_1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label_2.Click, Label_3.Click, Label_4.Click, Label_5.Click, Label_6.Click, Label_7.Click, Label_8.Click, Label_9.Click, Label_10.Click, Label_11.Click, Label_12.Click, Label_13.Click, Label_14.Click

    Dim enent_text As String = (Strings.Split(CType(sender, Label).Text, "_")(0))
    MessageBox.Show("clcik: " & enent_text)

End Sub
```

But how can I remove the Handles? If I hvae more labels in the future (ex: 50),
To prevent enter the labels. I don't want assign labels.

```
Private Sub Label_1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label_2.Click, Label_3.Click, Label_4.Click, Label_5.Click, Label_6.Click, Label_7.Click, Label_8.Click, Label_9.Click, Label_10.Click, Label_11.Click, Label_12.Click, Label_13.Click, Label_14.Click, Label_15.Click, Label_16.Click, Label_17.Click, Label_18.Click...., Label_50.Click
```

I Just wnat to be this, to remove all Handles's item, and I expect it can run.

```
Private Sub Label_1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim enent_text As String = (Strings.Split(CType(sender, Label).Text, "_")(0))
    MessageBox.Show("clcik: " & enent_text)

End Sub
```

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You do not want to alter the code if new labels are added? Is this your aim?

Comment: @icbytes Yes, I expect to do this, can remove Handles anything

Comment: Then you need a entirely other approach. Usually you should try to create an approach where you define that all labels belong to one group ( like using tag property or a groupbox or panel). Then you would need a const string which is part of each labels name. With this in mind you can assign the eventhandlers during runtime, in a foreach loop. Lets say in OnShow. The handler routine would need to be written as generic as possible in order to avoid altering it ,too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should create the controls dynamically, similar to the old VB6 array of controls.  You can assign a single handler, and add or remove controls as needed.  see [How to create Control Arrays in VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net)