# Is it possible to group multiple PictureBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I can drag a PictureBox onto a Form Control, a Tab Control or a Panel Control, etc. And I can import an image into a PictureBox. However, I don't know how to group multiple PictureBoxes together in Visual Studio 2017. Looks like there is no such a function. I need this function because I want to generate a big picture based on the user's input. That big picture consists of multiple small pictures, the visibility of which is controlled by the user through multiple checkboxes.

In Excel, I could put multiple pictures in it, group them together, use the VBA to control the visibility of each picture, and finally copy that picture group into a Word file. I would do this in a VSTO Word Document project in Visual Studio 2017 using vb.net.
I added some pictures for demonstrate the expected function.
[Picture 1 shows the small pictures to be used in a big picture. (Please ignore the .vslx file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxdxc.png)
[Picture 2 shows a possible result based on user's input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xspym.png)

Comment: [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net

Comment: @Jimi, not very clear about the usage of the TableLayoutPanel. After searching, I feel the picture I'd generate is much more complicated than the TableLayoutPanel can do. Sorry I didn't post a example in the original question. But you can google 'process and instrument diagram' to take a look. Now, I have two options to do it. Option A, to do this in Excel as I said in the question. Option B, use copyfromscreen to capture the screen and paste into the word. I think there must be more options out there. Also, I want to hide the whole process to the user. Appreciate if you can help more on this.

Comment: A `TableLayoutPanel` represent a managed Grid, somewhat similar to what Excel provides: a (Column, Row) indexed structure. This Control is used to organize other Controls in a ordered disposition. Well, it's a Grid. You can insert in a specific Cell any Control that can show a Bitmap (PicureBox, Panel, Label etc.). As Hans Passant suggested, manage the Controls you insert in a Grid using a Collection tool, so you can reference/manage your Controls using the methods that a Collection offers (Add, AddRange, Remove, RemoveAt, IndexOf or indexed access to its members).

Comment: In other words, when you add (with whatever means) a new Bitmap, assign the Bitmap to a Control that can show it, add the reference of this Control to a `List(Of Control)` (or, better, a specialized class that you can use to manage you collection of Bitmaps), use the `TableLayoutPanel` for presentation: it can help in keeping your Controls organized in the UI and can handle the UI resizing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own custom control.
 here is an example/suggestion how to do it with a `User control` that can be reused across your application.
 the user control is holding panels in a matrix, you can set a drag&drop `Event` to each `Panel` control and the user will be able to drop a picture box on each panel:

**USER CONTROL:**

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Public NumberOfPanelsInRow As Integer
    Sub New(ByVal height As Integer, width As Integer, Optional ByVal numberofPanelsInRow As Integer = 3)

        ' This call is required by the designer.'
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.'
        Me.Height = height
        Me.Width = width
        Me.NumberOfPanelsInRow = numberofPanelsInRow
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' grouped panels to hold picturebox you can drag & drop to them...'
        Dim panelHeight As Integer = Me.Height / NumberOfPanelsInRow
        Dim panelWidth As Integer = Me.Width / NumberOfPanelsInRow
        Dim colors() As Color = {Color.Pink, Color.Black, Color.Red, Color.Cyan, Color.Green, Color.Orange,
            Color.Red, Color.Pink, Color.Black, Color.Red, Color.Cyan, Color.Green, Color.Orange, Color.Red}
        Dim total As Integer = NumberOfPanelsInRow * NumberOfPanelsInRow
        Dim currentYlocation As Integer = 0
        Dim currentXlocation As Integer = 0
        Dim location As Point = New Point(0, currentYlocation)
        Dim rowcounter As Integer = 0
        Dim itemcounter As Integer = 0
        For i = 1 To total

            If rowcounter >= NumberOfPanelsInRow Then
                rowcounter = 0
                currentYlocation += panelHeight
                currentXlocation = 0
            End If

            ' to each one of this panel you can drag a picture box'
            Dim p As New Panel
            p.Size = New Size(panelWidth, panelHeight)
            p.Location = New Point(currentXlocation, currentYlocation)
            p.BackColor = colors(itemcounter)
            Me.Controls.Add(p)

            rowcounter += 1
            itemcounter += 1
            currentXlocation += panelWidth
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

**CALLING THE USER CONTROL FROM FORM1:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim uc = New UserControl1(300, 300)
        Me.Controls.Add(uc)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**GUI OUTPUT:**

[image]