# How to convert Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.PictureBoxArray into .net 4.7.2

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I’m trying to migrate my project VB6 to .net 4.7.2 but PictureBoxArray class now obsolete. Below I mentioned my code.

```vb
Private component As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
Public WithEvents IMG_LIGHT As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.PictureBoxArray

Me.IMG_LIGHT=New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.PictureBoxArray(components)
```

How to fixe that code.

Comment: The best course of action depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. Control arrays in VB6 existed so that you could handle events for multiple controls with a single method. VB.NET has a different mechanism for that. If you need array functionality beyond that then you create an array of `PictureBoxes` in code the same way you do a `String` or `Integer` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as you used to in VB6 but there are solutions to get the behavior you are looking for, it depends what that is as @jmcilhinney mentioned.

One easy approach is to iterate through controls in the Controls collection of a Form (or any control in which you can place other controls, like GroupBox):

```
Dim pictureBox As PictureBox
Dim control As Control

For Each control In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf control Is PictureBox Then

        ' Get PictureBox
        pictureBox = CType(control, PictureBox)

        ' Do something with PictureBox

    End If

Next
```

In a similar loop, when your controls are initialized, you can use AddHandler to add a common event handler for all the PictureBox controls:

```
For Each control As Control In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf control Is PictureBox Then

        ' Get PictureBox
        pictureBox = CType(control, PictureBox)

        AddHandler pictureBox.Clicked, AddressOf PictureBox_Clicked

    End If

Next
```

This could be your common event handler for Clicked event for all your PictureBoxes:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pictureBox As PictureBox = sender

    ' Handle PictureBox Click event in here

End Sub
```

To identify your individual PictureBox controls, you could store an index value in the control's `Tag` property. This is not as pleasant as having VB6 indexing your controls for you but it should work. You could auto-index your controls in the same loop as you are adding an event handler.

See the following posts:

1. [How to create Control Arrays in VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net): see **Looping Through the Controls Collection** in the 2nd answer, might be what you are looking for.
2. [Control Arrays in VB.NET](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?627956-Control-Arrays-in-VB-NET)

Comment: Étienne I think it would be a good idea to copy the key elements of those external pages into your answer. External links will eventually end up dead and the answer therefore much less useful.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the reminder. Added a simple example.