# How can I use iteration to make this vbnet code more efficient?

Tags: vb.net

```
Function set_bar_positions()
    bar_x(0) = delocateX(bar1.Left)
    bar_y(0) = delocateY(bar1.Top)
    bar_x(1) = delocateX(bar2.Left)
    bar_y(1) = delocateY(bar2.Top)
    bar_x(2) = delocateX(bar3.Left)
    bar_y(2) = delocateY(bar3.Top)
```

This snippet from one of my functions show what I'm trying to do. These lines repeat almost identical until the end of the function where this is called:

```
    bar_x(29) = delocateX(bar30.Left)
    bar_y(29) = delocateY(bar30.Top)
```

> I have tried iterating this functions by doing stuff like this, but now I know I can't:

```
Dim num As Integer = 0
bar_x(num) = delocateX(bar(num)).Left)
```

I am trying to make this code more efficient and have less lines. Anyone have an idea I can implement?

Comment: Basically the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59663957/6843158 What are you trying to achieve ? Loop on form controls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Controls.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_)

```vb
For i = 0 To 29
    Dim cs = Me.Controls.Find("bar" & i.ToString(), True)
    If cs.Any() Then
        Dim c = cs.First()
        bar_x(i) = delocateX(c.Left)
        bar_y(i) = delocateY(c.Top)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get 3 errors saying "$" character is invalid, and that "c" is not declared?

Comment: @Pyth0nN00b then you're not using the latest Visual Studio. I'll change it to the older style syntax for you.

Comment: Cheers I didn't even know - using whatever the college installed

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=Sequence contains no elements
  Source=System.Core

Comment: On `i` = what? does the control `bar` & `i` exist for that `i`? (you should break the code in debug to inspect `i`). Either way, I'll add a safeguard against that case

Comment: Cheers your solution worked perfectly, could you assist in optimizing more code? I'll post a new question

Comment: @azzamatron I will help you if I can