# How can I improve this iterative function?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to simplify this function which is similar from

```
Function Snake_makestep()
        maincar.Location = locate(xpos, ypos)
        car0.Location = locate(posx(0), posy(0))
        car1.Location = locate(posx(1), posy(1))
        If car2.Visible = True Then
            car2.Location = locate(posx(2), posy(2))
        End If
        If car3.Visible = True Then
            car3.Location = locate(posx(3), posy(3))
        End If
        If car4.Visible = True Then
            car4.Location = locate(posx(4), posy(4))
        End If
```

To

```
If car30.Visible = True Then
            car30.Location = locate(posx(30), posy(30))
        End If
    End Function
```

I'm not sure If I can/how to use Controls.Find solution within this function. Any help?

Comment: The winforms designer is a trap, always aim to separate the model from the view.  We can't see the type of car0, but guess, start fixing this with List(Of PictureBox).  To eventually end up with a List(Of Car).

Comment: @HansPassant Could you explain what I should do in layman's terms?

Comment: @azzamatron a better design would be to have a class which represents your data. You operate on objects of that class instead of operating on the UI directly. The class could have events which your form can handle to update the UI. This is the `Car` Hans was referring to. An answer with this design isn't quite appropriate for this site. jmcilhinney has answered your question. Combine it with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60712363/832052) to your original question, using `Controls.Find()` as needed (if your controls are in a container for example).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked:

```
For i = 2 To 30
    Dim car = Controls("car" & i)

    If car.Visible Then
        car.Location = locate(posx(i), posy(i))
    End If
Next
```

`Visible` and `Location` are both members of the `Control` class so it doesn't matter what type of control those *car* variables are.

Note that this assumes that all controls are on the form itself. If they are in a different parent container, you'd need to use the `Controls` collection of that container.

Also, I have started `i` at 2 there, so you'd still need the explicit code for `car0` and `car1`. If they are always visible then you could start the loop at 0 and it would still work, saving you those two lines of code as well.