how to create private subs for new picturebox in vb 2008
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim t As Integer = 484
        Dim i As Integer = 32
        Dim ex_picbox(t) As PictureBox
        Dim zhj As Integer = 0
        For b = 1 To t / i
            For f = 1 To i + 1
                Dim pb As New PictureBox
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i) = pb
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Width = 22 'or whatever
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Height = 23
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Top = 367 + f * 29 - 29 'or whatever
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Image = My.Resources.black
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Name = "PictureBox" & CInt(f)
                If f = 1 Then
                    Button1.Text = "PictureBox" & CInt(f)
                End If
                ex_picbox(f + b * i - i).Left = 367 + (28) * b
                Me.Controls.Add(pb)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

i want to create a private sub for these pictureboxes. can someone help?
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
        Close()
    End Sub

i thought this would work but it doesnt allow to start with it

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299986/529282

Rather than calculating the location of all the controls, add a TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel to the form and then just add the controls directly to it. Those containers will take care of the layout.

Are you really using VS 2008? That's a decade and a half out of date. Given that you can get VS 2022 Community for free, I would suggest that you upgrade if you possibly can.

Your terminology is wrong. It's not that you want to "create a private sub for these pictureboxes". It's that you want to handle the MouseClick event of each PictureBox. To handle events of controls created at run time, the process is always the same:

Write the event handler method that you usually would, but without the Handles clause.
Inside the method, use the sender parameter to access the object that raised the event.
When you create the object, use an AddHandler statement to register the event handler.

For step 1, until you're familiar with writing your own event handlers, you can add a control in the designer, generate an event handler for it, then delete the Handles clause. If you're confident, just write the method yourself.
Private Sub PictureBoxes_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    'Use pb here.
End Sub

For i = 1 To 10
    Dim pb As New PictureBox

    '...

    AddHandler pb.MouseClick, AddressOf PictureBoxes_MouseClick

    Controls.Add(pb)
Next


You must declare the PictureBox array as class field. I.e., outside of the Sub:
Private ex_picbox() As PictureBox

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As Integer = 484
    Dim i As Integer = 32
    ReDim ex_picbox(t)
    Dim zhj As Integer = 0
    For b = 1 To t / i
        For f = 1 To i + 1
            Dim pb As New PictureBox With {
                .Width = 22,
                .Height = 23,
                .Top = 367 + f * 29 - 29,
                .Image = My.Resources.black,
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                .Name = "PictureBox" & CInt(f),
                .Left = 367 + (28) * b }
            ex_picbox(f + b * i - i) = pb
            If f = 1 Then
                Button1.Text = "PictureBox" & CInt(f)
            End If
            Me.Controls.Add(pb)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Now, you can use this array in another Sub:
Private MyOtherSub()
    For Each pb As PictureBox In ex_picbox
        'Do something with pb
    Next
End Sub

In the Click event handler, the sender is the PictureBox you clicked. Therefore, you can cast it to PictureBox and use it directly:
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click
    ' ^^^ You can use the same Click event handler for all PictureBoxes

    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    'Do something with pb
End Sub

You need to create only one event handler and you can then select it for all your PicturBoxes in properties window (switch to events by clicking the flash-icon).
If you do not need the MouseEventArgs containing the mouse coordinates and the button pressed (Left, Middle, Right), you can use the Click event instead of MouseClick event.
Also, you can simplify creating the PictureBox by using an object initializer.
